# Site for implementing a research papers without code

Tags: research, implementation, code

Before a couple of months, I found a web page for implementing papers which are published without code. Someone posts a paper on it and then community competes to implement that paper.

But I don't remember the name of the page and I cannot find it anymore. Any help?

Answer (score -1):

Follow [Kristian Kersting](https://ml-research.github.io/), a former professor of mine at University of Bonn who was involved in that event. That was actually a workshop for (if I remember right) NIPS.

**UPDATE**: well … [I found it](https://mltrain.cc/events/nips-highlights-learn-how-to-code-a-paper-with-state-of-the-art-frameworks/) :D

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for, that's just an event. The page I'm looking for is like  "github for research papers without code" on which there are competitions for implementing those papers.